# Reviewable Module Form Field Integrated Into Testimonial Module

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using the [Reviewable module](https://github.com/camfindlay/silverstripe-reviewable/blob/master/code/ControllerExtension.php) just for the form field that gives a star rating a user can select.

That produces a form field with a hidden field called 'score' for a 1-5 rating a user can pick.

I'm trying to modify this [Testimonials](https://github.com/guru-digital/silverstripe-testimonials/blob/master/code/pages/TestimonialPage.php) module and page so I can use that rating field and it is submitted and written to the database. I'm having issues passing it into the validateSubmission function I guess because the rating is never stored in the database. It is always 0.

I'm probably just going to fork the Testimonials module so I don't mind hard coding the changes into the module instead of using data extensions.

I added the reviewable form field to the TestimonialForm FieldList but having problems passing to validate the submission function.

From TestimonialForm()

```
$fields = new FieldList(array(
        TextField::create('Author', 'Your Name'),
        TextareaField::create('Content', 'Your Testimonial'),
        \Reviewable\RatingField::create('Rating', 'Please rate us out of 5 stars'),
    ));
```

Comment: So you want a user to create a testimonial AND rate his exeperience with 1...5 ? Reviewable module creates a pseudo many_many object, where any user can rate a DataObject / Page etc...on the page. And it creates an avarage of all star ratings.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to have both. I looked at both modules but the way I describes it works best for what I'm after. This for a service based business, and the page needs to have each rating individually for schema markup for SEO.

All I'm trying to do is pass the rating field from the Reviewable module I linked, into the Testimonial module and have it properly write to the database. I linked to all the proper pages where I'm hoping somebody can see how that would happen.

Comment: That FormField seems to be tightly coupled with the current Rateable implementation which calls its own controller and saves to a seperate table. I guess it cannot be used for unsaved objects. You might create your own FormField that adds like a fancy dropdown and saves in a Enum in the Testimonial DataObject directly.